# How do I completly remove jekyll, ruby, and all ruby gems?

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I don't know much about ruby.

I was trying to get jekyll running on this computer a few months ago. I remember that I installed jekyll and several ruby gems following different tutorials and without taking proper notes. To add to the confusion, only some of it was through `apt install`. Some of them were `gem install`.

I want to try again, and I think I'd be better off with a blank slate to start with. As I'm not currently using ruby for anything else, I'm happy to remove it. But will this also remove all ruby gems?

`rvm implode`

> Command 'rvm' not found, but there are 19 similar ones.

`sudo apt purge ruby` has removed a lot, but I don't know whether gems are still around.

Comment: Did you look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950260/how-to-uninstall-rvm) from Stackoverflow in your research?

Comment: That suggests `rvm implode`, which didn't work for me.